# consulta compleja django ORM

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-models, mysql-workbench

tengo un problema que me esta reventando la cabeza y no he podido resolver. No se como realizar una consulta mediante el ORM de Django para obtener el resultado correcto. Estoy usando MySQL, La situación es la siguiente:

**Modelos**

```
class Prestamo(models.Model):
    PENDIENTE = 1
    PAGADO = 2
    FUSIONADO = 3
    ANULADO = 4
    ESTADOS = (
        (PENDIENTE, 'pendiente'),
        (PAGADO, 'pagado'),
        (FUSIONADO, 'fusionado'),
        (ANULADO, 'anulado')  

        )

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_prestamo = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    capital_prestado = models.FloatField()
    meses_plazo = models.IntegerField()
    porcentaje_aplicado = models.ForeignKey(Interes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor_interes = models.FloatField(null=True)
    saldo_capital = models.FloatField(null=True)
    saldo_interes = models.FloatField(null=True)
    tipo_prestamo = models.ForeignKey(TiposPrestamo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    prestamo_nuevo = models.ForeignKey('Prestamo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= True, null=True)
    #estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoPrestamo, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, default=1)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADOS, default=PENDIENTE, blank= True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0},{1},{2}".format(self.fecha_prestamo, self.cliente, self.capital_prestado)

class Abono(models.Model):
    prestamo = models.ForeignKey(Prestamo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_abono = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    valor_abono_capital = models.FloatField()
    valor_abono_interes = models.FloatField()
    observaciones = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoAbono, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0},{1}".format(self.fecha_abono, self.valor_abono_capital)


class Descuento(models.Model):
    prestamo = models.ForeignKey(Prestamo,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_descuento = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    valor_descuento = models.FloatField()
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    descontadopor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "descuento: {0}, {1}".format(self.fecha_descuento, self.valor_descuento)
```

En la base de datos tengo los siguiente datos de ejemplos para las tablas relacionadas a los modelos anteriores.

**Tabla prestamo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla de abonos**

[image: Tabla de abonos]

**Tabla Descuento**

[image: Tabla descuento]

Por medio de django ORM estoy tratando de obtener un listado en donde se muestre cada préstamo por registro, la información que debo mostrar son: `id_prestamo`, `capital_prestado`,`fecha_prestamo`,`porcentaje`,`cliente`, **`abonos_capital`**, **`descuentos`+* y **`saldo_capital`**

Ha sido realmente difícil para mi mostrar los campos anteriores que se encuentran en negrita ya que se me duplican los valores tanto de **descuentos** como de **abonos a capital** y por supuesto esto afecta al campo **saldo capital**. Esto es debido a los left join que automáticamente genera django ORM.La consulta que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
Prestamo.objects.values('id','capital_prestado','fecha_prestamo','porcentaje_aplicado__porcentaje').annotate(cliente=Concat('cliente__nombres', V(' '),'cliente__apellidos'),abonos_capital=Coalesce(Sum('abono__valor_abono_capital'),V(0)),abonos_interes=Coalesce(Sum('abono__valor_abono_interes'),V(0)),descuentos=Coalesce(Sum('descuento__valor_descuento'),V(0)),saldo_capital=F('capital_prestado')- F('abonos_capital') ,saldo_interes=F('saldo_capital') * F('porcentaje_aplicado__porcentaje')/100.0 ).filter(estado=1).order_by('fecha_prestamo')
```

Sin embargo la anterior consulta usando el ORM me trae el listado con cálculos incorrectos, de la siguiente manera:
[image: Listado de prestamos, calculos erroneos]

No quiero usar consultas sql desde django, sino usar el ORM. Pero la consulta SQL que me trae los datos como los necesito es la siguiente:

```
select p.id,fecha_prestamo,p.capital_prestado,CONCAT(clientes_cliente.nombres,' ', clientes_cliente.apellidos) 'Cliente',
IFNULL(sum(prestamos_abono.valor_abono_capital), 0) abonos,
(select IFNULL(sum(prestamos_descuento.valor_descuento) , 0) from prestamos_descuento where prestamos_descuento.prestamo_id = p.id) 'descuentos',
(p.capital_prestado - IFNULL(sum(prestamos_abono.valor_abono_capital), 0) - (select IFNULL(sum(prestamos_descuento.valor_descuento) , 0) from prestamos_descuento where prestamos_descuento.prestamo_id = p.id)  ) 'saldo capital'
from prestamos_prestamo as p left join prestamos_abono ON prestamos_abono.prestamo_id = p.id
                        inner join clientes_cliente ON p.cliente_id = clientes_cliente.id
group by p.id,fecha_prestamo,p.capital_prestado,clientes_cliente.nombres,clientes_cliente.apellidos;
```

Y me trae los siguiente datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde capital prestado es el campo que se encuentra en la tabla **Prestamo**, abonos a capital, es la suma de abonos que tiene el préstamo y están en la tabla **abonos**, y los descuentos, se encuentran en la tabla **descuentos**. Teniendo en cuenta los datos anteriores calculo el **saldo a capital** que cumple la siguiente formula matemática:

```
Saldo capital = valor_prestamo - (abonos + descuentos)
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de tus modelos en formato de texto y no como imágenes

Comment: listo, compañero.